# Why does an activity indicator still spin when an app is paused?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints, uiactivityindicatorview

I created a simple application with just a button and an activity indicator.  When I press the button I have the activity indicator start animating.  In Xcode 4.6 iPhone 6.1 Simulator I see the activity indicator spinning.  When I pause the application I sometimes land in libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap.  This appears to be on the com.apple.main-thread which is thread 1.  Shouldn't pausing the app this way block the main thread and so stop the activity indicator from spinning?  It doesn't appear to.

Update: This article ( http://www.dragthing.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-launch-faster/ ) says "As I discovered, the UIActivityIndicatorView animation is run on a thread by the system – that means, even though my application is blocked inside its initialisation code while it starts up, the spinner will still be spinning."  Is it possible the UIActivityIndicatorView is animated off the main thread?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: where u have called "stop animating" in u r code?

Comment: What do you mean, pause the app?

Comment: I press the debugger pause button in Xcode to "Pause program execution".  That's the tool tip that comes up when you hover over the debugger pause button.  If I pause the application I expect all threads in the application to stop but the animation still keeps going which lead me to believe the activity indicator doesn't run on the main thread.  The code is trivial - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}  I'm just doing something to start the activity indicator and wondering why it isn't stopping when I hit pause in the debugger.

Comment: Five years later I am wondering the same thing. In my case, I do a `sleep(timeInterval)` on the main thread. The Activity Indicator just keeps spinning. But for example the blinking text cursor (e.g. in a `UITextView` when editing) does indeed freeze.

Comment: I'm still looking for the answer, but looking in to UIActivityIndicatorView kinda sources (https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UIActivityIndicatorView.m), I've found out that it is built on CAKeyframeAnimation, which is processed by GPU. Maybe this is the reason? Xcode stops CPU processing, but not a GPU.

Answer (score 11):

A `UIActivityIndicator` draws its image using a `UIImageView` subview, and animates the image by attaching a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to the image view's layer. You can see the arrangement by printing the view hierarchy:

```
(lldb) po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7fd778808c00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000013b9ef0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x600001dcd400>>
   | <UIView: 0x7fd778d036f0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001dc5bc0>>
   |    | <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0x7fd778d00280; frame = (177 323; 0 0); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0.45; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001dc5a80>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd778d06680; frame = (-10 -10; 20 20); opaque = NO;
                 userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = {
                   contents=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x600001dc5f40>;
                   contentsMultiplyColor=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x600001dc5fa0>;
                 }; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001dc5ae0>>
```

Your app doesn't run these animations. Your app sends these animations to the window server and the window server runs them. That's why they keep running when your app is paused. All threads in your app are paused, but the window server is not paused.

You can prove this by stopping the simulator's window server. It is called `backboardd`. From the command line, run this command:

```
killall -STOP backboardd
```

You'll see that the activity indicator stops spinning. Then run this command to resume:

```
killall -CONT backboardd
```

Comment: This answer is correct. You can see this in the metal strace logs too - backboardd is the one sending the render commands. Sorry for the incorrect answer.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thank you both of you guys! @rob mayoff, how did you find out?

Comment: I figured it out by experimentation, based on things I have learned from watching many WWDC videos and general research.

Comment: Hi @robmayoff. Could you tell me, where can i find some information about window server in ios application. I tried , but didn't find anything

Comment: There's not really any public information about it, other than its name, “backboardd”. It was mentioned in [WWDC 2014 Session 419](https://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/419?q=backboard) and [WWDC 2017 Session 601](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/601/).